# Anchor tag link is not create in Asp.net core Area

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, anchor, area

I am creating controller with model in asp.net core 2. See above link is working.

```
<a asp-controller="Color" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.PkcolorId">Edit</a>
```

Render

```
<a href='/color/edit?id=1'>Edit</a>
```

But when I create in Area the it not working not convert into link

```
<a asp-area="Master" asp-controller="Color" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.PkcolorId">Edit</a>
```

Render

```
<a asp-area="Master" asp-controller="Color" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.PkcolorId">Edit</a>
```

can anybody help me for this issue.

Comment: Indent code blocks by 4 spaces :)

Comment: Well show us how you set up your areas.

Comment: Hello David,than you for the reply.   Firstly i have created Area in same of "Master"then i create controller with  "MVC Controller  with view  using entity framwork" then  controller and all the view is created , Listing in index page is showing but anchor tag is not working. and issue on create  view. monel name is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

please check route rules and ensure **Area route** are defined.

in **Startup.cs > Configure** check routes :

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "default",
        "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    // --- Check this route exists ---
    routes.MapRoute(
        "areas",
        "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

best Regards.